# How do I connect to Kindle Fire for development?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

What do I need to do to use my Kindle Fire for android development?  (Specifically for testing my apps on the device.)

Comment: In addition to the below, for me it was necessary to reboot my computer to get it to recognize the new USB settings.  I resisted doing this for quite awhile as it should ideally be sufficient to restart the particular service(s).  If all else fails, try that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can find the instructions for connecting Kindle Fire to the ADB in a [PDF of instructions](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf) provided by Amazon.

Paraphrased from the document:

1. Edit the adb_usb.ini file (located in ~/.android/)
2. Add the lines:

   > ```
   > 0x1949
   > 0x0006
   > ```
3. Save the file.
4. Run these commands to restart adb:

   > ```
   > adb kill-server
   > adb start-server 
   > adb devices
   > ```

NOTE: For Windows 7 users you need to download [an additional driver](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/kindle-fire-windows-7-driver.zip).

Comment: It's perfectly ok and encouraged to answer your own questions to document things *(just for anyone who doesn't know)*. I won't upvote this though since [answers which only contain a link are bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). This answer gets useless when the link goes down. Which is probably the time people start searching for docs how to actually do that on alternative sources.

Comment: @alextsc Thanks for the comment. I've updated the answer to include the necessary changes attempting to cut out the verbosity from the linked document.

Answer (score 16):

Linux uses a different way to set up the device. According to [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up), you need to set up your Linux system as follows:

1. Edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` as root, and add the following line (create this file if it does not exist):

   > ```
   > SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1949", MODE="0666"
   > ```
2. Change the permission of this file by executing the following command as root:

   > ```
   > chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
   > ```
3. Reload the rules by executing the following command as root:

   > ```
   > udevadm control --reload-rules
   > ```
4. Run these commands to restart adb:

   > ```
   > adb kill-server
   > adb devices
   > ```

If everything is ok, you will see your Kindle Fire listed as a device.

Comment: This ain't working... I did exactly what you said. My KindleFire is still not showing up in the list of attached devices.

Comment: just used also adb start-server before adb devices and everything worked fine on ubuntu. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking forward how to connect Kindle on the ADB, so what I had to do is:

Go to **Settings->Security** and **Enable ADB**.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Mac, this probably works similarly from a Windows box.

First I configured the Kindle Fire to allow sideloaded apps.  This isn't the default behavior, you have to click a checkbox in the settings.

From the Fire, I went to the app store and downloaded a DropBox app (free.)

From my dev machine, I registered on the DropBox website (also free.)

This gives you a dropbox folder on your dev box that will be synced automagically to your dropbox folder on the web.

Then, to develop, I compile the app to make a new apk, drag it to the dropbox folder, and use the DropBox app on the Fire fetch the apk file.  It loads with the click of a button.  It takes about 15 seconds tops to get the apk to the Fire.  I don't need any extra cables, etc.

Comment: ... and there's no way to get a debug console this way.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a user defined site in Android SDK Manager:

> Launch Android SDK Manager >>  Tools >> Manager Add-on Site >> User
>   defined>> add http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml

Then download the Amazon Kindle drivers from Android SDK Manager

Then then enable ADB from kindle settings.

> Settings >> Device >> Enable ADB

And run \extras\amazon\kindle_fire_usb_driver, run KindleDrivers.exe

[More info](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/05-setting-up-your-kindle-fire-tablet-for-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [PDF](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf)

In eclipse go to android SDK manager, select Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites -> select User Defined sites.

Select New and add the url as http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml.

After adding that go to packages->Extras

Download Kindle Fire USB Driver.

Go to android SDK folder->amazon->install the drivers.

Last step: You can see the device at In Device Manager, under Kindle Fire, verify that the device appears as Android Composite ADB Interface.