# How to debug android application on Amazon Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, debugging, kindle-fire

For Debugging Android Application on Amazon Kindle fire, I referred to these links

- [Debugging android apps on the kindle fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189488/debugging-android-apps-on-the-kindle-fire)
- [How do I connect to Kindle Fire for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151527/how-do-i-connect-to-kindle-fire-for-development)

But Kindle Fire is not listed in *abd* devices

And I have Windows 7 64 bit OS.

Comment: you need to mention you PC OS type.

Comment: have you installed the usb driver for your kindle fire, and enabled USB Debbuging in your deviec?

Answer (score 1):

following the instructions at https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/emulator-guide.html you need to make sure you edit the .inf file so it finds the Fire, and also ensure that you have ADB Debugging turned on as well as the ability to install applications turned on (both from Settings on the device)