# "Could not find an Android device to connect to" Error from Flash Pro CS6

Tags: android, flash, air, kindle-fire

I'm developing an app for Kindle Fire using Flash Pro CS6. I selected "After publishing: Install application on the connected Android device". This produces the following error:

> Could not find an Android device to connect to. Please ensure that you have the phone connected, the correct drivers installed, and the phone has USB device debugging enabled.

Any suggestions on configuring my environment to make this work?

Comment: What have you already done? Connected the phone with USB? Installed the USB driver?

Comment: 1. I'm asking specifically about Kindle Fire, not a phone. 2. Of course, I connected it and I'm able to install my apps manually. It's just a pain and takes a minute or so. Plus, I'd like to use debugging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to Kindle Fire for development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151527/how-do-i-connect-to-kindle-fire-for-development)

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks! Now if I could also use the debugger. There seems to be a problem doing that with AIR 3.x: [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423923/debugging-adobe-air-apps-on-kindle-fire)

Comment: Joachim, since this question is basically a duplicate, should it be deleted? If not, can you post your response as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup for the Kindle can be a bit unintuitive, but the whole process is described in [this PDF](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/sdk/Connecting_your_Kindle_Fire_to_ADB.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

this is solution Adobe Official Help CS5, CS5.5. You'll be helpful.

[error-could-find-android-device](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/error-could-find-android-device.html)